# R: regex, all except

Tags: r, regex

I have columns in my dataframe like

```
1234-sd
1234-abs
1234-mean
1234-min
```

I want to do a `selection` with matches so that only `1234-mean` is selected.
I tried something like `dplyr::select(matches("^1234-*(!mean)"))` but this doesn't work.
Any ideas ?:)

Comment: It should be `^1234-(?!mean$).*`

Comment: throwhs an error inside dplyr::matches() :/

Comment: Just searched for the `matches` function and it seems it accepts the `perl` argument, so try `dplyr::select(matches("^1234-(?!mean$).*", perl=TRUE))`

Answer (score 0):

On a vector

```
> x=c("1234-sd","1234-abs","1234-mean","1234-min")
> grepl("\\d+-mean",x)
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dplyr's `select()` with `-` to drop a specific column. Note that your variable names are [non-syntactic](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/names-values.html#non-syntactic) and you need to escape them with `` ` ``:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(`1234-sd` = c(1,2,3),
                 `1234-abs` = c(1,2,3),
                 `1234-mean` = c(4,5,6),
                 `1234-min` = c(1,2,3),
                 check.names = FALSE)

df %>% select(-`1234-mean`)
#   1234-sd 1234-abs 1234-min
# 1       1        1        1
# 2       2        2        2
# 3       3        3        3
```

Comment: I have other variables in this dataframe that would be de-selected with that command. sorry did not mentioned this

Comment: @Ai4l2s Then you really should edit your question and provide a minimal example of your input and expected output...